Branch and bound algorithm
I'm trying to implement branch and bounds algorithm in order to find optimal solution for transportation problem with truck loading limitations. In other words, I have 6 ton trucks and I use them for transportation in order to find minimal total price for transportation.
Here is my code:
import numpy as np
from scipy.optimize import linprog

# Global variables
node_counter = 0
best_solution = (None, float('inf'))  # (solution, total cost)
truck_capacity = 6  # in tons


def calculate_total_cost(solution, cost_per_ton):
    """
    Calculate the total transportation cost considering truck capacity.
    """
    total_cost = 0
    for i, flow in enumerate(solution):
        trucks_needed = int(np.ceil(flow / truck_capacity))  # Number of full truckloads
        total_cost += trucks_needed * truck_capacity * cost_per_ton[i]  # Cost for full truckloads
    return total_cost


def branch_and_bound(bounds, depth=0):
    global node_counter, best_solution

    # Transportation cost matrix (flattened)
    cost_per_ton = np.array([
        10, 8, 5, 9, 16,
        4, 3, 4, 11, 12,
        5, 10, 29, 7, 6,
        9, 2, 4, 1, 3
    ])

    # Supply constraints
    A_ub = np.zeros((4, 20))
    A_ub[0, :5] = 1
    A_ub[1, 5:10] = 1
    A_ub[2, 10:15] = 1
    A_ub[3, 15:] = 1
    b_ub = [17, 8, 10, 9]

    # Demand constraints
    A_eq = np.zeros((5, 20))
    for i in range(5):
        A_eq[i, i::5] = 1
    b_eq = [6, 15, 7, 8, 8]

    # Solve LP relaxation
    res = linprog(cost_per_ton, A_ub=A_ub, b_ub=b_ub, A_eq=A_eq, b_eq=b_eq, bounds=bounds, method='highs')
    node_counter += 1

    if res.success:
        solution = res.x
        total_cost = calculate_total_cost(solution, cost_per_ton)

        # Debug output
        print(f"Depth {depth}: Solution = {solution}, Total Cost = {total_cost}")

        # Check for a new best integer solution
        if all(val.is_integer() for val in solution):
            if total_cost < best_solution[1]:
                print(f"New best integer solution found at Depth {depth}: Total Cost = {total_cost}")
                best_solution = (solution, total_cost)
            return  # Stop branching as the solution is already integer

        # Branch on all fractional variables
        for i, val in enumerate(solution):
            if not val.is_integer():
                # Floor and ceil values respecting truck capacity
                floor_val = (int(val // truck_capacity)) * truck_capacity
                ceil_val = floor_val + truck_capacity

                # Branch lower: restrict variable to [0, floor_val]
                new_bounds_lower = bounds[:]
                new_bounds_lower[i] = (0, floor_val)
                print(f"Branching Lower on variable {i} at Depth {depth}")
                branch_and_bound(new_bounds_lower, depth + 1)

                # Branch upper: restrict variable to [ceil_val, None]
                new_bounds_upper = bounds[:]
                new_bounds_upper[i] = (ceil_val, None)
                print(f"Branching Upper on variable {i} at Depth {depth}")
                branch_and_bound(new_bounds_upper, depth + 1)

                break  # Ensure this branch handles only one variable at a time


# Initialize bounds
initial_bounds = [(0, None)] * 20

# Execute the Branch-and-Bound algorithm
branch_and_bound(initial_bounds)

# Format the best solution for output
if best_solution[0] is not None:
    solution_matrix = np.array(best_solution[0]).reshape(4, 5)  # 4 sources x 5 destinations
    print(f"Best integer result (matrix):\n{solution_matrix}")
else:
    print("No feasible integer solution found.")

print(f"Objective value (considering truck capacity): {best_solution[1]}")
print(f"Number of explored nodes: {node_counter}")

I receive solution:
Best integer result (matrix):




D1
D2
D3
D4




S1
0
10
7
0


S2
3
5
0
0


S3
3
0
0
0


S4
0
0
0
8



Objective value (considering truck capacity): 330$.
Number of explored nodes: 1
Unfortunately, the answer is wrong, because I solved the problem using other method and for 6 ton trucks the allocation and total price are:
Total price: $276.00




D1
D2
D3
D4




S1
0
6
5
6


S2
0
6
2
0


S3
6
0
0
0


S4
0
3
0
2



import pandas as pd
import pulp

truck_capacity = 6
suppliers = pd.RangeIndex(name='supplier', stop=4)
consumers = pd.RangeIndex(name='consumer', stop=5)

supply = pd.Series(
    name='supply', 
    index=suppliers, 
    data=(17, 8, 10, 9),
)
demand = pd.Series(
    name='demand', 
    index=consumers, 
    data=(6, 15, 7, 8, 8),
)
price_per_tonne = pd.DataFrame(
    index=suppliers, columns=consumers,
    data=(
        (10,  8,  5,  9, 16),
        ( 4,  3,  4, 11, 12),
        ( 5, 10, 29,  7,  6),
        ( 9,  2,  4,  1,  3),
    ),
).stack()
price_per_tonne.name = 'price'

flow = pd.DataFrame(
    index=suppliers, columns=consumers,
    data=pulp.LpVariable.matrix(
        name='flow_s%d_c%d', cat=pulp.LpContinuous, lowBound=0,
        indices=(suppliers, consumers),
    ),
).stack()
flow.name = 'flow'

trucks = pd.DataFrame(
    index=suppliers, columns=consumers,
    data=pulp.LpVariable.matrix(
        name='trucks_s%d_c%d', cat=pulp.LpInteger, lowBound=0,
        indices=(suppliers, consumers),
    )
).stack()
trucks.name = 'trucks'

price = truck_capacity * pulp.lpDot(price_per_tonne, trucks)
prob = pulp.LpProblem(name='transportation', sense=pulp.LpMinimize)
prob.setObjective(price)

# The flow must not exceed the supply
for supplier, group in flow.groupby('supplier'):
    prob.addConstraint(
        name=f'flow_supply_s{supplier}',
        constraint=pulp.lpSum(group) <= supply[supplier],
    )

# The flow must exactly meet the demand
for consumer, group in flow.groupby('consumer'):
    prob.addConstraint(
        name=f'flow_demand_c{consumer}',
        constraint=pulp.lpSum(group) == demand[consumer],
    )

# The capacity must be able to carry the flow
for (supplier, consumer), truck_flow in flow.items():
    prob.addConstraint(
        name=f'capacity_s{supplier}_c{consumer}',
        constraint=truck_flow <= trucks[(supplier, consumer)] * truck_capacity
    )


 

print(prob)
prob.solve()
assert prob.status == pulp.LpStatusOptimal

print(f'Total price: ${price.value():.2f}')
print()

print('Flow:')
flow = flow.apply(pulp.value).unstack(level='consumer')
print(flow)
print()

print('Trucks:')
trucks = trucks.apply(pulp.value).unstack(level='consumer')
print(trucks)
print()

print('Prices:')
print(trucks * truck_capacity * price_per_tonne.unstack(level='consumer'))

Any your help or ideas what to change in the code will be appreciated. Thanks in advance.

You say I solved the problem using other method - so implement that method in your code. I'm not going to try to guess the method that you used instead of the one that you presented. This question needs more information.

@mikeb  The question is updated
